# Possibilities communication between multiple (>20) Windows 8 RT devices (running same app) C# WI-FI

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, wifi-direct, proximity

I want to develop an WinRt App which will be running on PC's or tablets with Windows 8 (RT).

One PC/tablet with this app should be a "master" and this one will communicate with the other "slaves" (running same app). The number of slaves must be over 20!

All the computers are using the same (wifi) network.

I experimented with the PeerFinder-class (Wifi-direct), but I found this limitation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241210.aspx:

> You can connect to only one peer at a time if your app is in the peer
>   or client role. If your app is in the host role, you can connect up to
>   ***5 clients*** at a time.

What possibility can I use for this kind of communication?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Would bluetooth work for you?  How far away are the machines from each other?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think bluetooth will not work stable. The maximum distance between the 1st and the last computer could be 200 meters

Comment: Nope that wont work, bluetooth only works for 10 meters.  I'm interested in this, I'm working on a similar project.  The wifi direct would work for me, but i need cross platform.